# Changing the index of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am stuck at this the following problem. I am trying to create an array with pre-specified size and elements. Later I ask the user to provide me a name they want to add. I then create a new array of one size bigger and add the name new on the last place. Later I ask the user to provide me with a name from the array they wish to remove. And that's where the problem arises. I know I can use the method Array-Copy etc. but I want this to be solved only through index. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "Adam", "Eva" };
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.Write("Skriv in ett namn du vill lägga till: ");
        string newAdd = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] addedNames = AddName(names, newAdd);
        foreach (var item in addedNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.Write("Ange det element du vill ta bort: ");
        string tabort = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] removedNames = RemoveName(addedNames, tabort);

        foreach (var item in removedNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    static string[] AddName(string[] names, string newAdd)
    {
        string[] newNames = new string[names.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            newNames[i] = names[i];
        }
        newNames[newNames.Length - 1] = newAdd;
        return newNames;
    }

    static string[] RemoveName(string[] addedNames, string tabort)
    {
        string lLName = tabort.ToLower();
        string[] newnames = new string[addedNames.Length - 1];

        if (lLName == addedNames[0].ToLower())
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < addedNames.Length; i++)
            {
                newnames[index] = addedNames[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        else if (lLName == addedNames[addedNames.Length-1].ToLower())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < addedNames.Length-1; i++)
            {
                newnames[i] = addedNames[i];
            }
        }
        else if (lLName != addedNames[addedNames.Length-1].ToLower() && lLName != addedNames[0].ToLower())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < addedNames.Length; i++)
            {

            }
        }

        return newnames;
    }
}
```

}

So you can see that I am trying to implement the last else if statement, but I am not sure how to deal when the name provided by the user appears somewhere in my addedNames array except on the first and last places.

I would also love if you think there is an easier way to deal with the problem instead haveing almost 4 if statements for each case. It seems for me that if one manages to implement the last if statement then it will work regardless where the name, provided by the user to be removed, iss located in the addedNames array.

Comment: why not using a List? has been created as "battery-included" object for dealing problems like your's...

Comment: The exercise is supposed to be done with arrays :)

Comment: exercise? we shouldn't give hints, then? anyway, start from an `IndexOf` function, which gives you the position of an element in the array. I think you'll be just one step from the goal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0

Comment: Exercise of myself, not in a school.

Comment: I wante to do it withou any help functions. Just indexing. Do you think there is a way of solving it by index?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! If you need to add more information to your question, click "edit" and add it in - please don't paste additional information as a comment or answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just find the index of the name that needs to be replaced (tabort), and just change the value to newAdd?

```
string newAdd = Console.ReadLine();
string tabort = Console.ReadLine();
int i = Array.FindIndex(names, x => x.Contains(tabort));
names[i] = newAdd;
```

Comment: Can you explain how you mean? Do you mean I should instead ask the user which element they want to delete and ask them to provide me the index of it and then delete it that item? If yes, then I did that and that was very easy. I wanted to try to solve the exercise by asking the user to provide me with the name of the element they want to delete from the array. And I realized it is a hard one.